# How to combine and update two xml files with LINQ c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to combine these simple xml files:

result2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sports>
  <Sport id="1">
  </Sport>
</Sports>
```

result3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sports>
  <Sport id="1">
  </Sport>
  <Sport id="2">   
  </Sport>
</Sports>
```

I'm trying with that C# code:

```
static void Main()
{
  XDocument xml1 = XDocument.Load("result2.xml");
  XDocument xml2 = XDocument.Load("result3.xml");

  var combinedUnique = xml1.Descendants("Sport")
                     .Union(xml2.Descendants("Sport"));

  foreach (var item in combinedUnique)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(item);
  }
}
```

and the result I expect is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Sports>
      <Sport id="1">
      </Sport>
      <Sport id="2">   
      </Sport>
    </Sports>
```

But I get this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Sports>
      <Sport id="1">
      </Sport>                                                                                           
      <Sport id="1">
      </Sport>
      <Sport id="2">   
      </Sport>
    </Sports>
```

Can you propose how to make this C# code to work for this particular case?
I tried that for arrays and it is working 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, even though the elements share the same value for their `id` attribute, they are still different objects and will not be considered equal by either `Distinct` or `Union` simply because some arbitrary attribute value is equal.

If you need do a "distinctBy", you can use the following pattern (grouping on the property in question, then selecting the first element from each group):

```
var combinedUnique = xml1.Descendants("Sport")
                         .Concat(xml2.Descendants("Sport"))
                         .GroupBy(xe => (int)xe.Attribute("id"))
                         .Select(g => g.First());
```

Notice that I also replaced `Union` with `Concat` because the additional (set-based insertion) work done by `Union` is ineffective for this case, so we can go with the more efficient `Concat` (union all).

It probably makes sense to wrap this up into an extension method:

```
public static class LinqEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, 
                                                     Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        return src.GroupBy(keySelector).Select(g => g.First());
    }
}
```

so now you can:

```
var combinedUnique = xml1.Descendants("Sport")
                         .Concat(xml2.Descendants("Sport"))
                         .DistinctBy(xe => (int)xe.Attribute("id"));
```